# Set Date Time Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

i have shell script to set date and time automatically, on boot up after connecting to internet, my script is as follows

`RESULT="`wget -qO- http://xx5.xx2.xx6.x1:7019/api/values/getcurrenttime`"`

`echo Current Time $RESULT`

`TimeSetRet="$(date --set=$RESULT)"`

`echo ret: $TimeSetRet`

output of above script as follow

`Current Time "23 MAR 2017 15:27:58"`

`date: extra operand ‘2017’`

Why is that error i am getting?
format is correct and if i try to do manually in command line i get result but in shell it is giving error,
please help me with this issue.

Comment: you probably need to have " or \" at the right place... it probably splits up the text as different arguments at the moment

Comment: @StianSkjelstad after adding '\' to right place as you said, "$RESULT\" problem has not solved,

Comment: Made it as an answer, so that you can close the question

Comment: What does the result of that `wget` look like? Also, wouldn't `ntpd` be a better solution? My Pis all have their time drift rather badly if I don't leave ntpd running all the time to make constant adjustments.

Comment: Also, if this isn't a data problem and is only a quoting problem, then you probably want to use: `TimeSetRet="$(date --set="$RESULT")"`. Otherwise, the first whitespace-split word becomes an argument to the `--set` option, but the *rest* of the `$RESULT` variable becomes additional arguments to the `date` command itself.

Comment: @ghoti i am new to linux, that's the reason i am confused with `ntpd`, latter i have resigned date time format on server side, i.e `ServerTime`=`wget -qO- http://xx5.xx2.xx6.x1:7019/api/values/getcurrenttime`

`ServerTimeFilter`=`echo $ServerTime | grep -o -P '(?<=").*(?=")'`

`echo Current Time Filtered: $ServerTimeFilter`
`echo Current Time NonFilte: $ServerTime`


`TimeSetRet`=`date $ServerTimeFilter`
`echo ret: $TimeSetRet`.

Comment: @ghoti have you worked on PIS? i.e Public/Passenger Information Screen?

Comment: @VirajPatil, yes, at my last $work I designed a digital signage network that included information screens. These days I manage a small network of R-Pi-based screens with a bit of dynamic content, and use Pis and other small systems for various personal projects. I've used both Linux and FreeBSD on them. In all cases, if you want to keep your clock in sync with the world, ntpd is the way to go. If you're having trouble with ntpd and documentation or existing forums don't help, **http://unix.stackexchange.com/** is the place to be. **https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/** might also be useful.

Comment: @ghoti Thank you for valuable information, Can you tell me how reliable is raspberry pi for PIS on commercial basses? And if i need any guidance for m you for PIS related how could i reach you? Currently i am working on PIS itself.

Comment: @VirajPatil - Raspberry Pi is probably fine as long as you work within its limitations. As for reaching me ... I'd be happy to help answer any questions posted to StackOverflow. If you want my attention on one of them, tag me in a comment. I'm afraid I don't have time for a consulting gig at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to have " or \" at the right place... it probably splits up the text as different arguments at the moment